# Getting the VEHICLE_TYPES description in the HERE MAP REST API

Tags: here-api

I use HERE MAP REST API to get the speed limit.

> [E.g.](https://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/tiles.json?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&meta=1&layers=SPEED_LIMITS_FC3%2CSPEED_LIMITS_COND_FC3%2CSPEED_LIMITS_VAR_FC3&levels=11%2C11%2C11&tilexy=658%2C1449%2C658%2C1449%2C658%2C1449)

In response, I can see JSON key: `value-VEHICLE_TYPES:1023`

What does `1023` mean? How can I know it is a track, sedan, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this by this request-

```
http://pde.cit.api.here.com/1/doc/layer.html?region=APAC&release=19146&layer=LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FC1&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy
```

**It is a bitmask (sum of values), e.g. 1 = cars, 32 = trucks, 33 = 32 + 1 = cars and trucks**